# Node JS - Queueing MySQL Insert Queries

Tags: node.js

I am running a Node application that listens to a TCP port that has 1000s of devices sending complex strings to at an interval of 10s. This information would then be inserted into a mysql table. Which simply means that in a minute, my application would have to process around 60k complex strings and insert them into a table.

Currently my application and the DB works perfectly and am able to insert the data to the db. On a futuristic perspective, I would want to implement a queuing system, where, the data is stored in a queue for inserting into the db. Thus ensuring , even in case of a bottleneck, my application runs smoothly.

What would I have to do, or what technology would best suit my requirement.

Currently, my application runs on AWS EC2 instance with 4 Core and 16 GB RAM.

The application is build on Node JS and the db is MySQL 8.

I have seen a lot of code based on Redis and Bull which does job queues. Would that meet my requirement?